# check if a string contain a command or not?

Tags: linux, bash

how to check if a string contains a command or not in bash Linux ?

I've tried to do this but it doesn’t work

```
read x ;
if [ $x -eq $0 ] ;then
echo x is a command
else
echo is a string;fi
```

can any one help guys ?

Comment: how do you define a command?

Comment: @anubhava a linux command like ls , cat , cp , grep ,..etc

Answer (score 2):

Use bash's builtin `type`

```
read x
type "$x"
```

To act on the results:

```
if type "$x" &>/dev/null; then
    # this is a builtin/function/alias/executable
else
    # this is not
fi
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type

Answer (score 1):

Any string can be a command. What you *can* do, is use `which` to find out whether an executable so named is on the `$PATH`.

Examine the output or exit status of `which $x`